# Trigger/Execute a java program from browser script

Tags: javascript, java, windows, registry

We are converting our java-swing based desktop app into web based using javascript + react. Our current swing app uses local file operations heavily and performs lot of read/write actions on client OS. As you know in browser environment it is not very easy/possible performing local file access because of security restrictions. I know there is File API in html5, but all file related operations needs user iteraction (file browse action should be originating from a real human, not by script). Additionally we have als other native features such as port reading etc which are not possible with browser and javascript. 
Can we trigger a java program from an html page in same manner for example the application *zoom* can start its native executable directly from an link. I think during the install of native executable zoom app, it registers himself to windows regedit etc. Can we make same thing for an java app?

Comment: if you have a good separation UI + business, what's to stop you from creating a rest service accessing your business logic?

Comment: we do not have a good separation UI + business. The app is a bit complex and demands low level native access to existing file system

Comment: well ... then I recommend re-writing the entire thing